# Specialization of template class containing template member is not working

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Why is `B<int>::bar<int> == true` and how to fix this?

Edit: looks like the problem is that B specialization is incorrect

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A {
  static bool foo;
};

template <class T>
struct B {
  template <class U>
  static bool bar;
};

// assigning default values (works as expected)
template <class T>
bool A<T>::foo = true;

template <class T> template <class U>
bool B<T>::bar = true;

// template specialization
template <>
bool A<int>::foo = false; // works as expected

template <> template <class U>
bool B<int>::bar = false; // not working

int main() {
  std::cout << A<char>::foo << '\n';       // 1
  std::cout << A<int>::foo << '\n';        // 0   works fine
  std::cout << B<char>::bar<char> << '\n'; // 1
  std::cout << B<int>::bar<int> << '\n';   // 1   why is it true?
}
```

looks like for some reason those lines of code are not setting `B<int>::bar<int>` to `false`:

```
template <> template <class U>
bool B<int>::bar = false;
```

Comment: Instead of multiple code fragments, can you show a single [mre], just one file containing the all the code in question that can be cut/pasted ***exactly as shown*** then compile, run, and reproduce your results?

Comment: IIRC if you want to specialize a structure you must specialize the whole full structure. See e.g. [this example on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sYxhbMv4c)

Comment: Works with clang, but not with gcc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9e3K137K9).

Comment: Msvc accept it too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c954Taenn)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you could try reporting it as a bug against GCC and see if they agree that it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is B::bar == true and how to fix this?

Because you've not correctly **explicitly specialized** `bar`. In particular, to explicitly specialize `bar` we have to use 2 `template<>`s, one for the enclosing class template and the other for `bar` itself(as it also is a templated).

Thus, to solve this make the following changes:

```
template <> template <>
bool B<int>::bar<int> = false; // works now
int main() {
  
  std::cout << B<int>::bar<int> << '\n';   // prints 0
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z85bsxKdM)